# Docker healthcheck based on logs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to add a healthcheck to the docker-compose that I'm using to runghcr.io/synesthesiam/homeassistant-satellite. In particular, sometime the container stops working and I can see in the logs the following:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054979' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054981' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054983' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054985' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054987' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054989' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054991' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054993' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054995' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054997' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
```

I tried adding the following, but it doesn't work:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "docker logs homeassistant-satellite 2>&1 | grep -i 'ERROR' || exit 1"]
      interval: 1m # How often to run the check
      timeout: 10s # Maximum time allowed for the check
      retries: 1 # Number of failures before marking unhealthy
      # Add this line to trigger restarts on failures
      start_period: 60s # Delay before restarting after failure
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: grep exits with 0 if it finds lines to return, so your healtcheck would be 0 (success) if there are errors in the log.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

The command is executed *inside* the container. Is there `docker` *inside* the container? Is `docker.sock` mounted?

You could start the container with a process that writes logs to a file. Looking at https://github.com/synesthesiam/homeassistant-satellite/blob/master/Dockerfile :

```
command: bash -c "python -m homeassistant_satellite | tee /logfile"
```

And then check if logfile has ERROR. I would truncate the log file so only new lines are considered.

```
grep -qi 'ERROR' /logfile; ret=$((!$?)); truncate -s 0 /logfile; exit "$ret"
```